# Flutter buid Eror

Tags: flutter, gradle, error-handling

Launching lib\main.dart on M2010J19SG in debug mode...
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Error while evaluating property 'filteredArgumentsMap' of task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
> > Failed to transform arm64_v8a_debug-1.0.0-04817c99c9fd4956f27505204f7e344335810aed.jar (io.flutter:arm64_v8a_debug:1.0.0-04817c99c9fd4956f27505204f7e344335810aed) to match attributes {artifactType=android-classes-jar, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
> > Execution failed for JetifyTransform: C:\Users\Slimo30.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.flutter\arm64_v8a_debug\1.0.0-04817c99c9fd4956f27505204f7e344335810aed\99c46dfdbaf03a40be30b183ed64a0bc07f3caa7\arm64_v8a_debug-1.0.0-04817c99c9fd4956f27505204f7e344335810aed.jar.
> > Java heap space

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 48s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

How to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

The error message suggests an issue with memory allocation while compiling your Kotlin code. To address this, you can adjust the maximum heap size (memory) allocated to Gradle.

Open the gradle.properties file and add the following line:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M
```

This directive configures the maximum heap size to 2048 megabytes (2 gigabytes). Feel free to modify this value according to the available memory on your system.